# Is there a way to import google script libraries in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea, google-apps-script, autocomplete, clasp

I'm working on google script projects and using `clasp` to sync code between my local machine and google scripts. 
My scripts are using other my scripts as libraries.

Is it possible to connect several google scripts projects in IntelliJ Idea? 
The difficulty here is that Google requires you to add some identifier/prefix (see screenshot) to libraries.
[image: google script add library] 
So if you have a library with variable `test`. You need to access it with `library-prefix.test`. What is the best way to make autocompletion in Idea for this situation?

Comment: Do you have the library source code? If so, It should be straight forward.

Comment: @TheMaster, yes, I do. the only problem is this prefix... How can I add it?

Comment: Are you using typescript/@types library for autocompletion?

Comment: @TheMaster, no. Currently, all files are pure js. Unfortunately, I know nothing about typescript. Is it the only way?

Comment: You would probably have to create a custom plugin with templating that allows for auto-completion for your libraries. Check IntelliJ's plugin documentation. The following tutorial might also help:
https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/01/how-to-write-custom-language-support-plugins/